# Регулярное выражение для mac-адреса

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо составить регулярное выражение для поиска в тексте mac-адреса в формате "01:23:54:67:89:AB".

В интернете встречал выражения типа

`^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$`

однако такое выражение не позволяет найти mac-адрес среди текста.

Такой вариант

`([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}`

ложно срабатывает, например, в 01:33:47:65:89:ab:cd, идентифицируя начало как mac-адрес. Как его можно модифицировать, чтобы добиться желаемого результата?

Comment: для начала придется описать все, что _не является_ mac адресом. что еще может такого встретится в тексте, что выглядит похожим на mac но им не является. и все эти случаи явно задать в выражении в виде отрицаний

Comment: @Mike неизвестно, что может встретиться

Comment: Тогда и выражение написать не возможно. можно конечно попробовать описать то, что должно окружать mac что бы он был таковым, например пробельные символы, к которым возможно стоит добавить запятую (если вдруг mac могут идти через запятую) и еще какие нибудь символы. очевидно, нельзя указывать двоеточие, раз встречаются более длинные последовательности через двоеточия, mac не являющиеся.

Comment: либо пойти методом исключения, сказать, что перед mac может быть только не двоеточие или начало строки (?<=([^:]|^)) и написать, что после него не двоеточие или конец строки (?=([^:]|$)). после чего обработать все возможные тексты и если будут замечены еще какие либо исключения добавить проверку на них то же

Comment: Странно, автор вопроса есть. Поставьте галочку - и вопрос отвечен, если не отвечен - под ответом - причину почему ответ не нравится.

Answer (score 1):

В подобных случаях главное - определить нужный контекст, в котором совпадения считаются валидными. В большинстве случаев достаточно использовать границу слов (определяются по-разному в зависимости от библиотеки регулярных выражений). В данном случае, `01:33:47:65:89:ab:cd` содержит совпадение шаблона `([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})`. Если же данное совпадение нужно отфильтровать, необходимо определить, что в этой строке есть такого, что поможет отсеять подобные строки.

Например, можно предположить, что помимо границы слова (между `ab` и `:cd` проходит граница слова) нужно отфильтровать совпадения, перед или после которых есть двоеточие. В таком случае добавьте блок предварительного просмотра вперёд/назад:

```
(?<!:)\b(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\b(?!:)
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/a0eTXW/1)

`(?<!:)` не позволит найти совпадения, перед которыми стоит двоеточие, а `(?!:)` - те, после которых есть двоеточие. Чтобы учесть дефисы, можно изменить это выражение следующим: `(?<![:-])\b(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\b(?![:-])`.